# Sending Email without contactKey

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm now looking for a way to send an email without a ContactKey on Marketing cloud, only with email address attribute.
Here's the details I'm now dealing with.

1. User attribute data will be transferred from Marketing cloud Personalization to MCE.
2. And there's a certain case that we cannot catch the user ContactKey data on MCP side (since there's no log-in feature on website we're now dealing with.).Only Email Address will be passed into MCP through pop-up registeration form on the website.
3. So some Contactkey data will come into MCE as NULL, nevertheless we still have to send an email in this case.(with certain campaign purpose)

From what I've tried on MCE, I cannot send an email with only Email Address.
It would be great helpful if anyone can give me some insights on this.
Thanks in advance!